# お昼は簡単に済ませる which one is correct? I eat a simple lunch. or i easily will finish lunch

Tags: grammar

> お昼は簡単に済ませる

which one is correct?

I eat a simple lunch.

or

I easily will finish lunch

[na-adjective + に particle?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33601/na-adjective-%E3%81%AB-particle)

Answer (score 1):

It means the former: *I eat a simple lunch*. お昼を簡単に済ます suggests eating something quick and light, maybe typically noodles, sandwiches etc.

Comment: why not the second one?
what the difference between お昼は簡単に and 簡単なお昼?
at first i thought why "I eat a simple lunch." is not 簡単なお昼

Comment: Sorry it was confusing - I edited. 簡単なお昼 is what is eaten when you say 簡単にお昼を済ます. Regarding why 簡単に does not mean *simply* or *easily* here, it is a matter of language use. It modifies お昼を済ます as a whole, not the verb 済ます.

Comment: To put in my two cents, I think the sentence can be transliterated as "Let the daytime/lunch easily/simply finish," which, if put into proper English, would be "Make the lunch simple (so it can finish/pass without much hassle)"